# Browser Version Test

Tags: html

The following code in my html file is working for me:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9 ]>
<p class="warning">This page uses newer browser features to display larger versions of the small  images appearing on the right hand side of the page and to enhance the appearance of the page. If you are seeing the message, your browser doesn't support some or all of these features.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

I want to expand it to test for other browsers, but I can't seem to find any documentation searching the web, probably because I don't know what to search for. What is the name language used in the test if that is what it is or how would I find documentation for it? I also need to find the names used for other browsers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [if lt IE9] is what is known as [conditional comments.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: Thanks. With that answer, I was able to find out that they only work in Internet Explorer and that I need another approach such as recommended by Rob Williams.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery includes a method of testing for which browser you're in:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

But you're much better off testing for whatever feature you're looking to use, rather than browser. The BrowserAgent string can be forged quite easily, so you'll sometimes get Firefox users masquerading as IE users, etc.

Comment: You're right about testing for features, which I found subsequent to the post. I would still like to know what the name of the code is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad subject, beyond the scope of an answer here. [CSS Browser Hacks For Firefox, Opera, Safari & Internet Explorer](http://www.nealgrosskopf.com/tech/thread.php?pid=20) should give you a good start.

And here is [reference for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromecompatfaq) browser by Google.

Comment: It seems to be a very specific question to me. Where is there documentation for tests like this: "<!--[if lt IE 9 ]>...
<![endif]-->" and what are the names of the variables for other browsers? I'm at a loss as to how that is a broad question. I'm not asking for an explanation of the language.

Comment: The tests that you are referring to are IE specific (meaning - those exist for IE only, for other browsers you need to use other methods - see my answer for a quick reference) and believe me, cross-browser compatibility is way beyond a scope of a simple answer :) Here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html you will find more information on IE conditional comments.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. All I wanted to know was what the code was called and Ray told me. From that, I was able to figure out the rest on my own. I guess I should have left out the further details.